# How to compile wireshark dissector plugin?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a wireshark dissector plugin. I went through chapter 9 of the wireshark documentation and also a few other websites. They say `Makefile.common` and `Makefile.am` have to be modified to reflect the relevant files and dissector name'. I have installed wireshark on my Mac. Searched in the `Applications/Wireshark.app` folder for Makefiles. Didn't find any. What is the process to compile a dissector plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Searched in the `Applications/Wireshark.app` folder for Makefiles. Didn't find any.

That's because there aren't any.  `/Applications/Wireshark.app` is a *binary* distribution of the Wireshark application; if you're going to be writing a plugin, you need to get the Wireshark *source code*.

Go to the [the Wireshark download page](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html), but click on "Source Code", not "OS X 10.6 and later Intel 64-bit .dmg" or "OS X 10.5 and later Intel 32-bit .dmg".

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best documentation is under the `README.plugins` and `README.dissector` which explains what files to add your plugin directory too. Also when you are done you are going to want to run `./autogen.sh` then follow the steps at the end of code. I hope this helps!